# Как вывести массив в обратном порядке без использования length

Tags: java

Создаётся массив целых чисел. Нужно вывести массив в обратном порядке.
У меня получается при помощи `.length`. Есть ли способ сделать это без `.length`, используя циклы `for-each` и арифметические действия?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("введите количество элементов");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("введите элементы");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Элементы в обратном порядке");
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `Iterator, Collections.reverse` не рассматриваем ?

Comment: нет@SeniorPomidor

Comment: Это задача на смекалку??

Comment: @GHosT практического смысла в ней точно нет, так что, что называется, "для общего развития".

Comment: @Сергей1127 то есть вы не хотите использовать списки (`List`), `Arrays.sort` и `.length`? А что насчет использования `num`?

Comment: да чисто,для общего развития

Comment: Тогда, либо вариант @GreyGoblin, либо вариант с Collections.reverseOrder()

Comment: Можно через рекурсию, но это невероятно неэффективно. В чем проблема использования .length?

Comment: @etki а как сделать через рекурсию с учетом всех ограничений? И с `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` связываться бы не хотелось. С `.length` проблем нет. Речь про альтернативы с точки зрения теории.

Comment: @Regent да это я чет тупанул. Но с AIOOBE можно сделать метод printall(array, offset), который сначала выводит все элементы после offset через самого себя, а потом тот, который находится по offset. При AIOOBE он просто игнорирует исключение и выходит.

Comment: @Regent хотя и с for такое тоже можно сделать, просто вести счетчик текущего индекса внутри самого for. В общем, безбрежный простор для странных решений.

Comment: @etki с рекурсией метода `printall` и единственным AIOOBE в нём мне вариант понятен, и при всей своей неэффективности он неплохо подходит к вопросу, хоть и AIOOBE основательно портит дело. А вот вариант с `for` не понял. Речь про предварительный подсчет количества элементов в массиве с помощью `for` и AIOOBE?

Comment: @Regent `for x in array { counter++; if (counter == offset) { printAll(array, offset + 1); } print x; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположим, что у нас просто есть массив, созданный где-то и как-то (то есть доступа к `num` и процессу его формирования мы не имеем). А также что нельзя проводить сортировку массива (как оригинала, так и копии) и использовать другие структуры данных (списки, стеки и т.д.). И, конечно, нельзя использовать `.length` у массива.

**Первый вариант**. Вычисление длины массива вручную:

```
int[] a = { 2, 3, 4 };
int length = 0;
for (int element : a)
{
    length++;
}
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Вместо `for-each` можно воспользоваться обычным циклом в связке с `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Второй вариант**. Использование рекурсии для вывода на экран (по предложению @etki) с ограничением рекурсии с помощью `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
private static void print(int[] array, int index)
{
    try
    {
        int element = array[index];
        print(array, index + 1);
        System.out.println(element);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) { }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 2, 3, 4 };
    print(a, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**1. Если цель вывести введенные данные в обратном порядке:**

```
System.out.println("введите элементы");
for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    a[i-1] = s.nextInt();
}
```

Соответственно вывод можно сделать просто:

```
System.out.println("Элементы в обратном порядке");
for (int i : a) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**2. Если массив трогать нельзя, а вывести надо в обратном порядке:**

Код вывода после наполнения массива:

```
String result = ""; 
for (int i : a) {
    result = i + "\r\n" + result;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, мы заранее знаем кол-во элементов, так как получаем его с консоли. Так что можно сделать так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("введите количество элементов");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("введите элементы");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Элементы в обратном порядке");
    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: В случае "считывает массив с консоли и выводим в обратном порядке"  текущий подход подойдёт. А вот если речь про "есть массив - нужно вывести в обратном порядке", то не подойдёт. Не знаю какой именно случай имел в виду автор. Посмотрим что скажет он.

Comment: Если есть массив, то без length никак. Преобразования вроде как должны все равно использовать length, если через Exception-ы, то это уже не простые арифметические операции.

Comment: Ну и в вопросе говорилось про арифметические операции. Конкатенация строк вроде к ним не относится.

Comment: Да, конкатенацию строк арифметической операцией не назвать. Но для самостоятельного массива (то есть без использования `num`) этот вариант, по моему мнению, ближе всего находится к заданию среди имеющихся ответов. Повторюсь: возможно, автора устраивает использование `num`  и он примет ваш ответ. Я же рассматриваю варианты без `num`, `length` и `List`.

Comment: Я за то, чтобы убрать 2., оставить 1.. Думаю он идеально подходит. Там и for и foreach.

Comment: Это вы сейчас про ответ GreyGoblin? В первом его варианте и массив портится, и есть "жульничество": изменение массива в момент его создания. Согласитесь: если бы просто был дан массив, то первый вариант не подошел бы от слова "полностью".

Comment: Да, про него. Вопрос начинается со слов "Создаётся массив целых чисел.". Задача похожа на университетсвую. Сомневаюсь, что там стоит цель сохранить порядок создаваемого массива.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что пытаюсь сделать условие задачи более строгим. Однако всё же было бы здорово видеть решения, работающие с уже созданным массивом (который просто взяли и передали в метод решения, без предыстории его создания) и не портящие его. Даже учитывая что это никому не пригодится в будущем - просто интереса ради. Изначально, кстати, текст был такой: "Массив из целых чисел".  Это уже я отредактировал (возможно, зря именно так) на "Создаётся массив целых чисел".

Answer (score 1):

Будем надеяться, вы просто проводите соревнование на самый неэффективный код

```
private static void reversePrint(int[] array, int offset) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int entry : array) {
        if (++index == offset) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (offset > index) {
        // значит, после полного прохода циклом до offset так и 
        // не удалось добраться - в массиве меньше элементов, и
        // выводить ничего не надо
        return;
    }
    reversePrint(array, offset + 1);
    System.out.println(array[offset]);
}
```

Из плюсов:

- Не генерирует исключение
- Тут совсем недалеко (но недостижимо из-за необходимости сохранения состояния) до tail recursion, что - вот ведь хохма-то - дало бы возможность компилятору заоптимизировать вызов до простого цикла
- Кубок неэффективности явно ваш - рекурсия + n²

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
String[] arr = new String[5];
Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder()); // Инвертирует массив arr
```

В примере:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("введите количество элементов");
    int num = s.nextInt();

    int a[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("введите элементы");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Элементы в обратном порядке");

    Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder()); // Инвертирует массив

    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Если вы инвертируете массив, то `i` в цикле должно расти от `0` до `a.length - 1`. 2. Вы используете `.length`, хотя в задании явно сказано. что его использовать нельзя. 3. Вы портите исходный массив.

Comment: Да, ошибся. Последний for надо заменить на foreach

Comment: Стоит исправить ответ. И это исправит только первые два пункта. Третий останется.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться стеком, тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("введите количество элементов");
int num = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("введите элементы");

Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    stack.push(scanner.nextInt());

while (!stack.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

Comment: Так это уже совсем нечестно: в вопросе ведь речь про массив. Тогда можно и `List` взять с обратным итератором.

Comment: @Regent а зачем использовать неподходящую структуру данных?)

Comment: Я, конечно, не автор вопроса, но в моём представлении вопрос должен звучать так: "есть массив целых чисел, как вывести элементы в обратном порядке без использования `.length`, `Arrays.sort`, `List` и прочих структур". Вопрос ведь теоретический: на практике все будут использовать `.length` и не заморачиваться.

Comment: @Regent ну если очень хочется массив, то пишем сначала в массив а потом в стек. Не вижу проблем переделать под конкретное решение - я лишь подбросил идею

Comment: Проблема, пожалуй, в том, что формулировка у автора достаточно мягкая, а я застрял больше чем на час на этом вопросе со своей более жесткой формулировкой, не допускающей использования доп. структур (списков, стеков и т.д.) . Надо завязывать с этим делом.

Comment: @Regent вообще задача элементарнейшая, т.к. мы уже знаем длину массива size (пользователь ее явно указывает), вопрос лишь в правильной замене переменных array.length на size

Comment: Да, достаточно воспользоваться переменной `num`. Вот именно поэтому мне хотелось бы, чтобы в формулировке просто фигурировал откуда-то полученный массив. Все эти свои "хочу" я собрал в своём ответе.

Answer (score 0):

еще один вариант, но тут нужно указывать размер массива. После новый массив можно использовать для своих нужд

```
    int size = 50;

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int secArr[] = new int[size];

    int index = 1;
    for (int i : a) {
        secArr[size - ++index] = i;
    }

    for (int i = size - index; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(secArr[i]);
    }
```

http://ideone.com/pLvy6q